# List within a list class definition

Tags: c#

I would like to create a list where I have 10 main points and associated 4 minor points as a List to each main point.
Lets say I have a class definition like this and a method:

```
public class Abc{
   public Point2D MainPoint { get; set; }
   public List<Point2D> MinorPoints { get; set; }

   public static List<Abc> AddValues(){
      var result = new List<Abc>();
      List<Point2D> newMinorPointsList = new List<Point2D>();

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          var newMainPoint = new Point2D(10 * i, 5 * i);
          for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
              var newMinorPoint = new Point2D(20 * i * j, 10 * i * j);
              newMinorPointsList.Add(newMinorPoint);
              }
          result.Add( new Abc() { MainPoint = newMainPoint, MinorPoints = new List<Point2D>(newMinorPointsList)});
       }
   }

   public static string PrintValues(List<Abc> pointList){
       string result = "";
       string resultMain = "";
       string resultMinor = "";
       string resultMinorString = "";
       var allPoints = new Abc();
       
       for (int i = 0; i < pointList.Count; i++){
          allPoints.MainPoint = pointList[i].MainPoint;
          allPoints.MinorPoints = new List<Point2D>(pointList[i].MinorPoints);
          
          for (int j = 0; j < allPoints.MinorPoints.Count; j++){
             
              resultMinor = allPoints.MinorPoints[j] + ", ";
              resultMinorString += resultMinor;
          }
       resultMain = "Main Point: " + allPoints.MainPoint + ", Minor Points: " + resultMinorString;
       result += resultMain;
   }
}
```

But I'm getting null reference exception at allPoints.MinorPoints = new List(pointList[i].MinorPoints); and it looks like values are not added into MinorPoints. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code never resets `newMinorPointsList` - did you mean to keep accumulating minor points across all the major points? Also, why do `new List<Point2D>(newMinorPointsList)`? And if you are printing, why do the spurious assigments to `allPoints`? It would also be helpful if your code compiled.

Comment: I ran the code and while it does nothing like it should and is very poorly written, it doesn't cause any exceptions.

Comment: Yes I'm newbie and all those points above are correct..newMinorPointsList should be cleared with every iteration to store only 4 points per major point..with new List<Point2D>(newMinorPointsList) I wanted to assign a list as AddRange did not work for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a re-write of your code:

```
public static List<Abc> CreateListOfAbc() {
    var result = new List<Abc>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        result.Add(new Abc() {
            MainPoint = new Point2D(10 * i, 5 * i),
            MinorPoints = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(j => new Point2D(20 * i * j, 10 * i * j)).ToList()
        });

    return result;
}

public static string PrintListOfAbc(List<Abc> pointList) {
    string result = "";

    foreach (var p in pointList)
        result += $"Main Point: {p.MainPoint}, Minor Points: {String.Join(", ", p.MinorPoints)}\n";

    return result;
}
```